# EBNF : missing the purpose of two production rules

Tags: ebnf, formal-languages

I have this grammar in EBNF for a sub-language with arithmetic & logical expressions, variables assignment and printing.

```
start   ::= (print | assign)*
print   ::= print expr ;
assign  ::= ID = expr ;
expr    ::= andExpr (|| andExpr)*
andExpr ::= relExpr (&& relExpr)*
relExpr ::= addExpr ( == addExpr | != addExpr | <= addExpr | >= addExpr | < addExpr | > addExpr)?
addExpr ::= mulExpr (+ mulExpr | - mulExpr)*
mulExpr ::= unExpr (* hunExpri | / hunExpr)*
unExpr  ::= + unExpr | - unExpr | ! unExpr | primary
primary ::= ( expr ) | ID | NUM | true | false
```

unfortunately I just can't figure out what these two rules:
***unExpr  ::= + unExpr

unExpr  ::= - unExpr***
actually do, or why I should need them, since I seem to be able to derive every phrase of the language without applying them. Any idea?
thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning no expressions like:

```
a=-1
```

(where "a" is an ID and "1" is a NUM)
in your language than you don't need those two rules.
Otherwise you have to implement them.

Comment: of course... I didn't foresee that. Thanks, you were very useful :-)